# How to clear cache of www?

Tags: xml, caching, web, unity-game-engine

Im using the www to download an xml file from a sever for my unity3d web application. It retrieves the file and everything works fine. The problem happens when i update the xml file in my server, unity doesn't seem to load the new data but instead shows the old data. Its doing some sort of a cache which doesn't really help me.

I looked at the docs and found WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload method but this only works for asset bundles.I also deleted the xml file in my server but when i run the application it still shows me the data from the initial xml i loaded(This confirms the cache).

Is there any way i can force unity to download a new version of my xml every time i download it rather than using the cache.

Hope I'm clear. Looking forward to some good suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Well, have tried that and it didn't work obviously as the problem happens even if i build it and upload it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can give a different URL to your WWW download code. Simply add a timestamp parameter. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/myfile.xml
```

Becomes

```
http://www.example.com/myfile.xml?p=13457889
```

Where 13457889 is the current time in milliseconds. Each URL will become unique and caching wont't take place.